# calculating jquery datatable column

Tags: jquery, datatables

inside jquery datatable I'm using sum plugin in order to sum values from particular column

```
 $('#example').DataTable( {
    drawCallback: function () {
      var api = this.api();
      $( api.table().footer() ).html(
        api.column( 4, {page:'current'} ).data().sum()
      );
    }
  } );
```

How can use this api call to calculate another column (for example column 6).

```
$( api.table().footer() ).html(
    api.column( 4, {page:'current'} ).data().sum()
    // calculate column 7 
);
```

also calculate result is injected inside first column of the footer instead of 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there but your reference to `api.table().footer()` got the whole footer. To target specific column footers you need to use `api.column(?).footer()`. That way your issue should be addressed like this:

```
$(api.column(4).footer()).html(
  api.column(4, {
    page: 'current'
  }).data().sum()
);
$(api.column(6).footer()).html(
  api.column(6, {
    page: 'current'
  }).data().sum()
);
```

Here's a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/xw9yyLqf/), hope that helps.

Comment: There was mention of totaling durations. I've updated the JSFiddle with a solution which uses momentJSs  duration (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) object.